# Get only the columns names from hdfs parquet file in shell script

Tags: unix, schema, parquet

Is there a way to get only the columns names from a parquet file in unix shell script as similar to below,

```
scala> df.columns
res3: Array[String] = Array(id,name, department,address,country)
```

In shell script I want this to be the value of variable `COLUMNS="id,name, department,address,country"`

I can then send this information to the sqoop export command. The parquet files do contain various columns, but they are all exported to the same table, so I can't use static columns.

Answer (score 1):

Usage in Hadoop
Prints out the schema for a given parquet file.

```
hadoop jar parquet-tools-1.9.0.jar schema hdfs://localhost:8020/test1.parquet
```

need parquet-tools-1.9.0.jar to attached and it will show you the columns.